# pypi not installing

Tags: python, pypi

**Why my pip not installing any solution for me
When i run pip install abir It show me error**

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement abir (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for abir

https://pypi.org/project/abir/0.1/

My setup.py

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
     name='abir',  
     version='0.1',
     scripts=['abir'] ,
     author="ABIR HOSSAIN",
     author_email="abirhossain200019@gmail.com",
     description="this is a test file",
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="https://github.com/ABIRHOSSAIN10/test",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

At https://pypi.org/project/abir/0.1/#files there are two files, both with extension `.egg`. Egg was a python packaging format but it's now old and outdated. `pip` lost ability to install eggs long ago.

You can install these eggs using `easy_install` — a pre-`pip` installation program. Please note there are eggs for Python 2.7 and 3.10 but Python lost `easy_install` at version 3.7 so you can only use `easy_install` to install an egg for Python 2.7.

To really fix the problem you should publish sdist (source distribution with extension `.zip` or `.tar.gz`) or wheel (`.whl`). Run

```
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and use `twine` to upload the generated packages.

*Upd*. This is how it installs now:

```
$ pip install phoneinfo
Collecting phoneinfo
  Using cached phoneinfo-0.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 kB)
Installing collected packages: phoneinfo
Successfully installed phoneinfo-0.1
```

Comment: its install now I get four files https://pypi.org/project/phoneinfo/0.1/#files

Comment: Now i face this problem    
.     /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 1: import: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 2: try:: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 3: import: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 4: except:: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `"pip install phonenumbers"'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/phoneinfo: line 5: `      os.system("pip install phonenumbers")'

Comment: That's a different problem and should be asked in a separate question; mention Termux in that question. `pip install phoneinfo` works for me in Linux command line.

Comment: Did you face this error or not

Comment: No. `pip install phoneinfo` installed that package in Linux.

Comment: Can you give the screenshot plz

Comment: See the update in the answer.

Comment: This is install on my terminal tow but when i run this phoneinfo i face that problem chek this on linux

Comment: That's a different problem and should be asked in a separate question. Pleas [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer and ask a different question.